# How to upload a file into a S3 bucket using a presigned url with Nuxt.js and Axios?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, axios, nuxt.js

I would like to use Axios on my Nuxt.js website to upload a file into a S3 bucket. I already managed the part to get the presigned URL. When I try to use the presigned URL with Postman, everything's working fine but when I try it with Axios I get this error: `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Access is not defined`.

Here is my code:

```js
<template>
  <v-file-input label="Select your file to upload" accept="image/*" v-model="myFile">
    File to upload to S3
  </v-file-input>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      myFile: null,
      ApiGatewayUrl: "https://xxxxxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/"
    }
  },
  methods: {
    uploadFile() {
      // get the pre-signed URL
      this.$axios.get(this.ApiGatewayUrl, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: this.$auth.strategy.token.get()
        }
      }).then((response) => {
      
        // now do a PUT request to the pre-signed URL
        this.$axios.put(response.data, {
          files: this.myFile
        }, {
          headers: {
            [Content-Type]: 'multipart/form-data'
          }
        }).then((response) => {
          this.setState({
            statusCode: response.status,
          })
        })
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

As it's working with Postman, I guess the error come from my Axios configuration.

Comment: I cannot compile the website with a dash if I remove the brackets, I get a syntax error...

Comment: Remove `[Access-Control-Allow-Origin]: "*",` completely and try again

Comment: And why do you have `Authorization: null,`? Split out getting the token from the request so you have some clearer code - that's a separate issue

Comment: I removed `[Access-Control-Allow-Origin]: "*",` and `Authorization: null,` from the header and also edit my post to make my code more cleaner. But even without these two props I still get the same error: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error`.

Comment: Thank you - what is the output of `response`?

Comment: I don't get any response output... 
And the error is still `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Content is not defined`, not `Network error` I have been disconnected.

Comment: Does `this.$auth.strategy.token.get()` have a value? Also please specify where the error is thrown

Comment: Yes this the cognito token I use it to get the pre-signed URL from my APIGateway. This part works great, I get the URL, but according to the Network tab of my browser, the PUT request is never done by Axios. The last request I can see is the GET request for the pre-signed URL

Comment: Try changing `[Content-Type]:` to `"Content-Type":`

Comment: Ok, seems working, I now see the PUT request but I receive a 400 error `InvalidArgument` instead of my previous error

Comment: I'd create a new question for that, finally got there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying your content type header wrong.

Replace:

```
headers: {
    [Content-Type]: 'multipart/form-data'
}
```

With:

```
headers: {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
}
```